# Hello, I have an Automation framework written in c# using specflow

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, specflow

I have been trying to open the project in the Visual studio 2017 community. But I am getting an following error while building the solution:

> error : SpecFlow designer codebehind generation is not compatible with MSBuild codebehind generation. The custom tool must be removed from the file. See http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild

But I was able to run the tests, Wierd!

Comment: It was probably running tests from a previous build that completed successfully. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: The link provided in the error message should give you the solution. What have you tried so far?

Comment: In fact, bullet point #2 is the answer to your question.